# How do I Mock database call in nested function?

Tags: php, laravel, testing, nested

I'm trying to write some tests for my code, and I stumbled upon this:
The code that I'm trying to test:

```
    public function prepareBundleProducts(object $bundle): array
    {
        $commonValue = fn ($identValue, $quantity) => [
            'productIdent' => [
                'productIdentType' => 'id',
                'identValue' => $identValue
            ],
            'addType' => 'SelectedSizes',
            'quantity' => $quantity
        ];

        return [
            $commonValue(strval($bundle->wheelsData->rimId), $this->determinateQuantity($bundle->wheelsData->rimId)),
            $commonValue(strval($bundle->wheelsData->tireId), 4.0),
            $commonValue(strval($bundle->wheelsData->wrapperId), 4.0),
            $commonValue('79193', 1.0),
        ];
    }
```

This function uses functions determinateQuantity which looks like that:

```
    private function determinateQuantity($rimId): float
    {
        return match (Products::where('id', $rimId)->pluck('unit')->first()) {
            'sztuka' => 4.0,
            'kpl.' => 1.0,
            default => throw new Exception('Nieznana jednostka miary dla felgi o ID: ' . $rimId . ' w bazie
             danych. Dopuszczone wartości: sztuka (4.0), kpl.(1.0). Sprawdzić to.'),
        };
    }
```

And now I'm wondering how do I write a test for this without actually calling to Database? I have no idea how to Mock a nested function. Has anyone had to deal with it already?

I'm trying to Mock a nested function and I don't know how to do it. Maybe my code need some refactoring so it's easier to test? I have never ever written a single test, so I have no idea how should I build my code around it.

Comment: You have to use a factory and fake that data using a real database, why can't you have a fake database and run in your test `Products::factory()->create(['unit' => 'sztuka']);`? It is as simple as that. Check my profile for answers about testing databases and how to use them on tests

Comment: You can mock the class which contains `determinateQuantity` but only mock that method using [`onlyMethods`](https://docs.phpunit.de/en/10.5/test-doubles.html#onlymethods) in the mock builder. That way you can just assert that it gets called with the correct parameter and you can determine a strategy on how to test that method on its own separately. Laravel's recommendation for testing the database is by using artificial data in a clean database rather than mocking database functions

Comment: Uh, okay. With a concept of using clean database it seems easier with the refreshDatabase and factories. Thanks.